# NTP time synchronization -

Tags: time, synchronization, ntp

I want to write synchro check in my VBS application but starting at the very beginning i think whole NTP synchro is doesn't work.

Please, advice me how can i check this?

My network:
1 station with WindowsServer2012R2 (set as NTP Server)
6 stations with Windows10Pro (set as NTP Clients)

From Client station - when i manually press "Update Now" - from:
Date and Time / Internet Time / Change Settings / -> Update Now. 
The time on client is updating.

But when set pooling interval to - for instance - every 5 minutes

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient]

"SpecialPollInterval"=dword:0000012c
```

When i change time during this 5 minutes, the time will be not synchronized.

Why?

I don't see any reason why it does not work?
What i am missing?

Comment: See [Windows Time Service Technical Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc773061%28WS.10%29.aspx) and [Windows Time Service Tools and Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc773263(v=ws.10).aspx) for detailed information

Comment: see the post here - it may help you; http://stackoverflow.com/a/34075586/3788685