# Programmatically sync time on Windows via NTP

Tags: windows, ntp

A Windows system in a domain synchronizes its time from a domain controller. 
Is it possible to synchronize it from an external server via NTP?

Thank you

Comment: Yes... What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Not sure. Client will probably be using Windows 7, Windows 10

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/34016933/3788685 that question & answer it may give you some ideas - let me know

Comment: Thank you, that solution worked for me.

Comment: that's good news :) I'll write you up an answer here for you to accept as that was one I did for another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't have to sync the time via the domain controller - but you do have to ensure that if your going to split things up in that way you need to make sure that the DC keeps correct time as it will have implications with things like Kerberos and you may find you start to get odd auth errors or failures.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34016933/3788685) question and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34075586/3788685) should give you enough details to get it working for workstations of Windows 7, and 8 - I've not tested Windows 10 yet but it should be very similar. Server versions may have slightly different settings, and certainly in Server 2012 or higher there is a group policy section which allows the setting and management of ntp specific stuff which can be applied to Windows 7 & above machines.

There are some details & screen shots [here](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2012&p=ntp&f=2) which show the server group policy side of things (2012).